# GIF/PPM to Greyscale Converter throws error "Coordinates out of range"

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, converters

So my current exercise is a program to convert a user chosen .gif or .ppm file to greyscale. I got the code, and from what I gather it should work, but when executing the program i get an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\greyscale.py", line 54, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\greyscale.py", line 43, in main
    image2convert = convert(image2convert)
  File ".\greyscale.py", line 29, in convert
    r, g, b = image2convert.getPixel(pixelx, pixely)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\graphics.py", line 933, in getPixel
    value = self.img.get(x,y)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3581, in get
    return self.tk.call(self.name, 'get', x, y)
_tkinter.TclError: pyimage1 get: coordinates out of range
```

Here is my code:

```
#greyscale.py -- Converts an image file to greyscale

from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename, asksaveasfilename
from graphics import *

def displayimage(imagefile):
    #Open image to get width and height
    image2convert = Image(Point(0, 0), imagefile)
    imgwidth = image2convert.getWidth()
    imgheight = image2convert.getHeight()

    #Set window size to image size and draw image to window
    win = GraphWin("Greyscale Converter", imgwidth, imgheight)
    image2convert.move(imgwidth/2, imgheight/2)
    image2convert.draw(win)

    return image2convert, win

def convert(image2convert):
    width = image2convert.getWidth()
    height = image2convert.getHeight()

    #For each row of pixels
    for pixelx in range(width + 1):
        #For each column of pixels
        for pixely in range(height + 1):
            print(pixelx, pixely)
            #Get Pixel Colour, calculate greyscale, set Pixel to calculated colour
            r, g, b = image2convert.getPixel(pixelx, pixely)
            brightness = int(round(0.299 * r + 0.587 * g + 0.114 * b))
            image2convert.setPixel(pixelx, pixely, color_rgb(brightness, brightness, brightness))
        #See progress for each row
        update(win)
    return image2convert

def main():
    imagefile = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("GIF-Image", ".gif"), ("PPM-Image", ".ppm")])

    image2convert, win = displayimage(imagefile)

    #convert after click
    win.getMouse()
    image2convert = convert(image2convert)

    #save new image
    outFile = asksaveasfilename(image2convert)
    newImg = image2convert.save(outFile)

    #close file and window after click
    win.getMouse()
    image2convert.close()
    win.close()

main()
```

Get pixel takes x and y coordinates as an argument and output a list of color values -> [r, g, b]

I really don't see why it doesn't work, i used print to output the x, y values each time and it looked correct too:

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
0 3
0 4
0 5
0 6
0 7
0 8
0 9
0 10
0 11
0 12
0 13
0 14
0 15
0 16
0 17
0 18
0 19
0 20
0 21
0 22
0 23
0 24
0 25
0 26
0 27
0 28
0 29
0 30
....
```

So it's iteraiting correctly through each pixel in the first loop but then fails at getting the Pixel colors.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try removing the `+1` on each `for` loop.

Comment: Damn, that worked. Sometimes it can be so simple lol.

Comment:  Yes, they go from zero to N-1. We've all done it

Comment: I did think about the n-1 part, that's why i added +1, but i didn't think further and consider the fact that the pixels start at zero hahaha